# get everything between <tag> and </tag> with php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab a string within a string using regex.

I've looked and looked but I can't seem to get any of the examples I have to work.

I need to grab the html tags <code> and </code> and everything in between them.

Then I need to pull the matched string from the parent string, do operations on both,

then put the matched string back into the parent string.

Here's my code:

```
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. &lt;code>Donec sed erat vel diam ultricies commodo. Nunc venenatis tellus eu quam suscipit quis fermentum dolor vehicula.&lt;/code>"
$regex='';
$code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
```

I've already tried these without success:

```
$regex = "/<code\s*(.*)\>(.*)<\/code>/";
$regex = "/<code>(.*)<\/code>/";
```

Comment: Tony the pony, he comes... [Have you tried an HTML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/707111)

Comment: Not really, this is no different to parsing a single BBcode tag. There are no attributes on it, just a straight `<code>(.*)</code>`

Comment: @minitech To parse a single BBcode tag? Sounds like a perfect situation for regex, no point getting Pear involved for something so simple.

Comment: @Joe: What if the single BBCode tag is surrounded in `[NOPARSE]`? What then? Malformed attributes? Custom extensions? AAGH!

Comment: to summarize, usually you wouldn't want to use regex to parse html as it has a complicated nested structure which regex was not built for parsing, but if it's just a one off with source that you can predict will be what you expect it to be, go for it.

Comment: I'm just taking a wild guess here, but given what he's asking, I don't think you need to worry about `[NOPARSE]` or anything silly: it's just "how do I match anything between THIS string literal and THAT string literal", where the string literals just happen to be XML tags. There's no additional variation possible on the string literals, so no point over-complicating it.

Comment: Why did you post the EXACT same question just 30minutes earlier?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252793/regex-to-match-a-string-in-a-string

Comment: that one didn't work, whic is this: $var = 'text<code>word</code>asdf'; and this:  $regex='#<code>(.*?)</code>#';

$code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches); print $code;
if ($code == 1)
{

Comment: I posted the same thing twice in a short time because the older post had a lot views and no answers (more so than most answered questions). But you're right, next time I'll be more patient, change the exmple, or use a combination of forums.

Comment: can a parser be installed in and used by a website? I'm looking to do this inline with a webpage. I'm not trying to code here, I'm tring to format database content and display it on a webpage

Comment: Please explain where you did you get the Var `$text` from? Your code in INVALID!! And no one saw that LOL :D

Answer (score 38):

You can use the following:

```php
$regex = '#<\s*?code\b[^>]*>(.*?)</code\b[^>]*>#s';
```

- `\b` ensures that a typo (like `<codeS>`) is not captured.
- The first pattern `[^>]*` captures the content of a tag with attributes (eg a class).
- Finally, the flag `s` capture content with newlines.

See the result here : http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1081

Comment: It doesn't work for tags that have no end tag, though. For example, it doesn't work on `<code id="me" />`.

Comment: This is completely natural because the question is to capture the contents of `<code>...</code>` tags and not to capture a self-closing tag (which does not concern the `<code>` tag).

Comment: instead of select whole text between the tags, how to select only selected charcters ?

Answer (score 30):

this function worked for me

```
<?php

function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

?>
```

Comment: can you explain why you're returning $matches[1] and not [0]?

Comment: $matches[0] is outerhtml of code you pass. for getting innerHtml you should get $matches[1]

Comment: You must have to add this in return for safer way : `return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;` if tag not present then it will give error so.

Comment: This works perfectly and should be the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: a tag work but it is not work with p tag

Comment: tested with

    <p style="margin: auto">Test P <div>content between p Tag</div></p>

and worked like charm. can you send your code to check?

Comment: perfect solution sir :).

Answer (score 24):

```
$regex = '#<code>(.*?)</code>#';
```

Using `#` as the delimiter instead of `/` because then we don't need to escape the `/` in `</code>`

As Phoenix posted below, `.*?` is used to make the `.*` ("anything") match as few characters as possible before it comes across a `</code>` (known as a "non-greedy quantifier"). That way, if your string is

```
<code>hello</code> something <code>again</code>
```

you'll match `hello` and `again` instead of just matching `hello</code> something <code>again`.

Comment: Should it be `(.*?)` in case the string contains multiple `<code>` tags (acknowledging that the example in the OP did not indicate this)?

Comment: i like the greedy option

Comment: I know this is way old... but... be very careful with the regex posted above. I have used this type of regex before on very large XML documents. Turn off the greedy setting, or you can wind up with catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Joe Why doesn't it work for string like `<tag>@github</tag>,<tag>@gcal-work</tag>,` (note the comma at the end)?......It is only picking the first tag...i.e @github. Any idea?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam you probably need to add the `g` flag to make the regex "global" - ie, make it return all matches rather than just the first one. Simply add a lowercase letter `g` after the ending delimiter, eg. `#<tag>(.*?)</tag>#g`

Comment: No problem - if the answer helped, would you mind upvoting it? Rep adds up over time :-)

Answer (score 7):

you can use `/<code>([\s\S]*)<\/code>/msU`
this catch NEWLINES too!

Comment: if you need a non-greedy option just put a question mark after the * '/<code>([\s\S]*?)<\/code>/msU'

Comment: I thought you liked the greedy option, stop touting non-greedy too :P

Answer (score 1):

```
function contentDisplay($text)
{
    //replace UTF-8
    $convertUT8 = array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6");
    $to = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...');
    $text = str_replace($convertUT8,$to,$text);

    //replace Windows-1252
    $convertWin1252 = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133));
    $to = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...');
    $text = str_replace($convertWin1252,$to,$text);

    //replace accents
    $convertAccents = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'Ð', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', '?', '?', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', '?', '?', 'L', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', '?', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'Œ', 'œ', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'Š', 'š', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Ÿ', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Ž', 'ž', '?', 'ƒ', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?');
    $to = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
    $text = str_replace($convertAccents,$to,$text);

    //Encode the characters
    $text = htmlentities($text);

    //normalize the line breaks (here because it applies to all text)
    $text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);
    $text = str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);

    //decode the <code> tags
    $codeOpen = htmlentities('<').'code'.htmlentities('>');
    if (strpos($text, $codeOpen))
    {
        $text = str_replace($codeOpen, html_entity_decode(htmlentities('<')) . "code" . html_entity_decode(htmlentities('>')), $text);
    }
    $codeOpen = htmlentities('<').'/code'.htmlentities('>');
    if (strpos($text, $codeOpen))
    {
        $text = str_replace($codeOpen, html_entity_decode(htmlentities('<')) . "/code" . html_entity_decode(htmlentities('>')), $text);
    }

    //match everything between <code> and </code>, the msU is what makes this work here, ADD this to REGEX archive
    $regex = '/<code>(.*)<\/code>/msU';
    $code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
    if ($code == 1)
    {
        if (is_array($matches) && count($matches) >= 2)
        {
            $newcode = $matches[1];

            $newcode = nl2br($newcode);
        }

    //remove <code>and this</code> from $text;
    $text = str_replace('<code>' . $matches[1] . '</code>', 'PLACEHOLDERCODE1', $text);

    //convert the line breaks to paragraphs
    $text = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
    $text = str_replace("\n" , '<br />', $text);
    $text = str_replace('</p><p>', '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p>', $text);

    $text = str_replace('PLACEHOLDERCODE1', '<code>'.$newcode.'</code>', $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $code = false;
    }

    if ($code == false)
    {
        //convert the line breaks to paragraphs
        $text = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
        $text = str_replace("\n" , '<br />', $text);
        $text = str_replace('</p><p>', '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p>', $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: This whopping piece of code should contain some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
function getTagValue($string, $tag)
{
    $pattern = "/<{$tag}>(.*?)<\/{$tag}>/s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
```

It returns empty string in case of no match.