# How we can fetch the data between HTML tags using regular expression in php

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I am new with the regular expression and i want to fetch the data(Address) between the  using regular expression here is my code

```
<th align="left" valign="top">Billed To:</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Shipped To:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="107" valign="top">
Logmet<br>
Wayne Rankin<br>
1400 Lake Bluff Cove <br>
Round Rock TX US 78665<br>
512-924-5437<br>
admin@logmet.com<br></td>
<td valign="top">
Logmet<br>
Wayne Rankin<br>
1400 Lake Bluff Cove <br>
Round Rock TX US 78665<br>
512-924-5437<br>
admin@logmet.com    </td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone know how i can get the address between these tags ... Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253027/get-everthing-between-tag-and-tag-with-php

Comment: am try to get address between <td height="107" valign="top"></td> that tag

Comment: Use an HTML Parser. Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: ya i tried with many expressions but i don't get the data .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some said already a regex isn't the best tool to use here... but if you MUST use it:

```
$chars=array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$html=str_replace($chars, '', $html);
preg_match_all('/<td.*?>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br><\/td>/', $html,$hits);
print_r($hits);
```

That one gets you EVERYTHING on each `td`, split in diferent array positions based on the `br`. If you just want to get some of them, remove the `()` of the ones you don't need

Comment: Thanks for your response.. am try with that code but its print blank array ...

Comment: totally true! edited my code. The problem are the `\r\n` or `\n` that may appear and the `.*` is unnable to read. If you remove them before parsing it works ^^.

Comment: thanks Mate ... its working now. It show now all td tab data .. once again thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the regular expression approach but when it comes to parsing html I use this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It's nice and clean and works well for me.