# regular expression to detect a tag

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to detect all the paragraphs in this file:

an XML file

to do so I used this code :

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<paragraph>\\s*?(.*?)\\s*?(.*?)\\s*?(.*?)</paragraph>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ne);
    int occur = 1;

    while(m.find()) {

        System.out.print("Word = " + ne.substring(m.start(), m.end())+"\n");        }


    }
```

the problem is that it only detects the first paragraph. Help please?

Comment: Why don't you just use an XML parser?

Comment: i don'g because it is not an XML file it is a segmented text, can i use it even if it is not ?

Comment: Sure looks like XML (with some HTML-ish entity references which can be taken care of) to me. What is "segmented text" if it's not XML?

Comment: What do you mean by "segmented text"? It looks like XML to me.

Comment: So how to use it ? XML parser i tried to use a code related to XML but it shows an error that the form is incorrect and it is not XML

Comment: Put an XML decleration and a root tag at the beginning, close the root tag at the end, and you'll be good to go (if all the tags get closed, that is).

Comment: would be please recommend me a link or anything thing to start with ? thank you for your help

Comment: About how to detect a tag you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253027/get-everthing-between-tag-and-tag-with-php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamer, as you said... for a "simple java project":

```
//import java.util.regex.Matcher;
//import java.util.regex.Pattern;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
text.append("<html><something>");
text.append("<paragraph><Sentence>text 1 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>");
text.append("<paragraph><Sentence>text 2 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>");
text.append("<zzz>this text wont go</zzz>");
text.append("<paragraph><Sentence>text 3 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>");
text.append("</something></html");
System.out.println(text.toString());

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<paragraph>(.*?)</paragraph>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text.toString());

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print("Word = " + m.group() + "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
<html><something><paragraph><Sentence>text 1 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>
<paragraph><Sentence>text 2 qwe</Sentence></paragraph><zzz>this text wont   
go</zzz><paragraph><Sentence>text 3 qwe</Sentence></paragraph></something>  
</html>
Word = <paragraph><Sentence>text 1 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>
Word = <paragraph><Sentence>text 2 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>
Word = <paragraph><Sentence>text 3 qwe</Sentence></paragraph>
```

Comment: Actually my code worked just fine when i changed the regular expression "<paragraph>([\\s\\S]*?)</paragraph>" , thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner using commons-lang:

```
String[] paragraphs = StringUtils.substringsBetween(ne, "<paragraph>", "</paragraph>");
```

Comment: Matt this is not working for a simple java project because i have to import