# Is there a way I can extract text from between 2 tags, and have output in a format of my choosing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, text

Is there a way I can extract text from between 2 tags, and have output in a format of my choosing? Are there any apps or scripts that can do this?

For example:

```
[b]1.[/b] [artist]Norman Bass[/artist] – How U Like Bass? (Warp Brothers     Club Mix) [i](3:26)[/i]
[b]2.[/b] [artist]Rhythmkillaz[/artist] – Wack Ass M.F. (Payback Mix - Clean Version) [i](3:23)[/i]
[b]3.[/b] [artist]Mario Piu'[/artist] & [artist]DJ Arabesque[/artist] – The Vision (Vision 1 Mix) [i](3:41)[/i]
[b]4.[/b] [artist]Cosmic Gate[/artist] – Fire Wire (Club Mix) [i](2:47)[/i]
[b]5.[/b] [artist]Push[/artist] – Strange World (2000 Remake) [i](6:02)[/i]
[b]6.[/b] [artist]Cortina[/artist] – Music Is Moving (Kumara Mix) [i](3:40)[/i]
[b]7.[/b] [artist]Public Domain[/artist] – Operation Blade (Original Mix) [i](3:44)[/i]
```

I would like to extract the information between the [artist] tags, and have it output as one line, with entries seperated by a comma.

Is there anything out there that can do this?

Comment: is there a single string?  do you want do it with php or js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php(using RegEx) :

```
<?php

function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#\[\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*\](.*?)\[/$tagname\b[^>]*\]#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

?>
```

Here we specify the tagname & get the data b/w it.

Reference : [get everthing between  and  with php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22891590/2142994)

In jQuery:

```
var regExp = /\]([^\[]+)\[/;
var matches = regExp.exec("[article]I expect five hundred dollars ($500).[/article]");

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(matches[1]);
```

This matched anything between `]` & `[`and logs it on the console.

Here we are searching for anything other than `[` in the string.

jQuery solution: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LwLt9ep9/)

Comment: Thanks that's perfet!

Comment: @Chris Good to know it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplistic regular expression in Javascript:

```js
var re = /\[artist\].+?(?=\[\/artist\])/g,
    artists = str.match(re).map(s => s.substr(8)),
    output = artists.join(', ');
```

If you need something more versatile you can encapsulate the same approach in a function:

```js
function getTag(str, tagName){
    var re = new RegExp(`\\[${tagName}\\].+?(?=\\[\\/${tagName}\\])`, 'g');
    return str.match(re).map(s => s.substr(tagName.length + 2));
}

getTag(str, 'artist').join(', ');
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3wb2ts25/2/) 
[Regex 101: explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iW1xY8/2/)

Comment: Note that template strings `\`...\`` and fat arrow `=>` functions are still new - you might consider falling back to string concatenation and regular functions for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do it

```js
var dataStr = "[b]1.[/b] [artist]Norman Bass[/artist] – How U Like Bass? (Warp Brothers     Club Mix) [i](3:26)[/i]\n[b]2.[/b] [artist]Rhythmkillaz[/artist] – Wack Ass M.F. (Payback Mix - Clean Version) [i](3:23)[/i]\n[b]3.[/b] [artist]Mario Piu'[/artist] & [artist]DJ Arabesque[/artist] – The Vision (Vision 1 Mix) [i](3:41)[/i]\n[b]4.[/b] [artist]Cosmic Gate[/artist] – Fire Wire (Club Mix) [i](2:47)[/i]\n[b]5.[/b] [artist]Push[/artist] – Strange World (2000 Remake) [i](6:02)[/i]\n[b]6.[/b] [artist]Cortina[/artist] – Music Is Moving (Kumara Mix) [i](3:40)[/i]\n[b]7.[/b] [artist]Public Domain[/artist] – Operation Blade (Original Mix) [i](3:44)[/i]",
   selected = dataStr.match(/[^\]]+(?=\[\/a)/g).join(", ");
document.write(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\[artist\](.*?)\[\/artist\]/", $str, $out);

For($i=0;$i<=count($out[1]);$i++){
   Echo $out[1][$i] . ",";
}
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fBW