# Sanitize content outside of [code] tags with one filter and content inside [code] tags with another filter

Tags: php, replace, bbcode, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I'm trying to sanitize comments on my page, but I only want to remove html tags etc. from content outside the `[code]` `[/code]` tags.

As for content inside the tags, I only want to use `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` on.

So if I have a comment that looks like this:

```
<a>some text</a>
<a>some text</a>
[code]<p>some text</p>[/code]
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
[code]<p>some text</p>[/code]
<div>hfghgf</div>
<div>some text</div>
```

My filter looks like this

```
function sanitize($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $data;
}
```

How can I now filter everything outside the `[code]` tags with my `sanitize()` function and then use only `htmlspecialchars()` on content inside the `[code]` tags. I also have to account for multiple `[code]` tags in one comment.

Comment: There are some tools that exist that will help you do this. Essentially you're just looking to break this up into an array of strings based on where the [code] tags are.  There are some tools out there that find markup and parse it into text and stuff, and they are pretty versatile. I'd start there, but I think this answer is bigger than a simple answer here. You should try a bunch of stuff first and ask questions if you're stuck. This should get you started. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: And also this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253027/get-everything-between-tag-and-tag-with-php

Comment: And you should also do a different sanitization for the code stuff as well. You don't want someone inserting javascript or something like that.

Comment: Thanks ill read and try this out. But why different sanitization, if i use htmlspecialchars the javascript can't run when < turns to &lt; right?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were saying you were only going to run that on stuff outside of the code tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample input, this seems a bit more direct:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aJrJD))

```
$data=<<<HTML
<a>some text</a>
<a>some text</a>
[code]<p>some text</p>[/code]
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
[code]<p>some text</p>[/code]
<div>hfghgf</div>
<div>some text</div>
HTML;

$data=strip_tags(                                                   // strip any residual tags from the string
        preg_replace_callback(
            '~\[code].*?\[/code]~is',                               // match [code]-wrapped substrings
            function($m){
                return htmlspecialchars($m[0],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');  // convert html entities as intended
            },
            $data
        )
    );

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
'some text
some text
[code]&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;[/code]
some text
some text
[code]&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;[/code]
hfghgf
some text'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the solution. If anyone else should need it here it is.

```
function sanitize($data) {

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $data;

}

$data = preg_split('/(\[code\])|(\[\/code\])/i', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // Split the array

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    if(($value === "[code]") || ($value === "[CODE]")) {
        $data[$key] = $value.htmlspecialchars($data[$key+1],ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').htmlspecialchars($data[$key+2], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // Set key with sanitized code block
        unset($data[$key+1]); // Unset old key with content inside code tags
        unset($data[$key+2]); // Unset old key with "[/code]"
    }

}

$data = array_values($data); // Reorder the array

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    if(!preg_match("/\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\]/i", $value)) {
        $data[$key] = sanitize($value);
    }

}

$data = implode(" ", $data);
```