# php - javascript - display executed script

Tags: javascript, php

is it possible to display all executed script on a web page ?

For example, I make a "file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/") in my code and I want to display all executed javascript link on my page.

I need to get this values :

[image]

Or that values : 
[image]

If it's possible, how can I do it ?

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: you have to parse the html and find all script tags

Comment: It's not exactly the same, for example, if you go to https://www.lenouvelliste.ch/ and check the tag and compare the executed script, you detect other script that was imported or that was not in html tags.

Comment: to add to @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ answer, you can use a regex in PHP to find those tags. See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9253072/1451422)

Comment: Yes, but what about the imported script ? like with "document.createElement("script");" and other method ? The goal is to scan wich script was loaded and executed.

Comment: @cretthie if you also want to get the scripts imported by others, you have to execute those scripts.

Comment: It also not possible easy to get a list of loaded script like on my firefox picture ?

Comment: perhaps `Panthere` https://github.com/dunglas/panthere could solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, I will check.