# Regex not removing data between tags

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove data between two tags such as -

```
<tag> To Remove </tag>
```

using `re.sub('<code>.*?</code>', '', text)`
However when the tags are directly preceded and closed by another tag it doesn't work. For example -

```
<tag1><tag2> To Remove! </tag2></tag1>
```

In this case it doesn't work. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Use `DOM/HTML` parser instead

Comment: Worth noting: [why you can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). "HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions."

Comment: Parsing HTML is a *solved problem*. Don't do it with regex. https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid external libraries, use this one:

```
(#<\s*?tag1\b[^>]*>.*?</tag1\b[^>]*>#s)
```

It also worked with tag2:

```
(#<\s*?tag2\b[^>]*>.*?</tag2\b[^>]*>#s)
```

The solution is from this link [get everything between <tag> and </tag> with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253027/get-everything-between-tag-and-tag-with-php).

As said there:

> - \b ensures that a typo (like codeS>) is not captured.
> - The first pattern [^>]* captures the content of a tag with attributes (eg a class).
> - Finally, the flag s capture content with newlines.

It is said php, but it also works with python. If you have any problems, remove the # and the #s.

If you can afford to use an external library, like bs4, it's as simple as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeaultifulSoup(your_doc, 'html.parser')
tag2 = soup.find_all('tag2')
for tag in tag2:
    tag.string = ''
```